# Javascript and the window.document object. How to change value in document

Tags: javascript, object, document

I have a normal page and popup window. On the popup window, I am modifying the javascript so the callback will change the value on my page (the page behind the popup window). But I am struggling on navigating back to that field in javascript.

I have the following:

window.document.getElementById('mynewfield').value =  newValue;

But this is not finding the field and needs to be changed to:

window.ID-OF-MY-WINDOW-BEHIND.document.getElementById('mynewfield').value =  newValue;

How can I find out what the ID is? Is there a print_r funciton for javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
window.opener
```

You can use this as follows:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('mynewfield').value = newValue;
```

Comment: Could you show me how to use it? Have looked at it on the w3 site but I can't figure out how to use it.